# JS variable scope of variable between two files

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I have a project setup in an IDE, with index.html that includes app.js. For testing purposes, I have also added (within the same project hierarchy) test.html that includes test.js. Now to me, although the two set of files are within the same project folder, they are independent because none of the two sets actually make a reference to the other set. So index.html doesn't reference test.html, and likewise app.js doesn't reference test.js and vice versa. Both app.js and test.js have the following code ...

```
var main = function () {
    "use strict";

    // need to do something
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

... but strangely, the variable `main` within app.js seems to link (pressing ctrl + click takes me) to the variable `main` within test.js! Why!? I am somewhat confused.

Comment: Presumably because you have a bug in your IDE.

Comment: I have tested the code within two separate IDES, netbeans and visual studio code... and both behave in the same manner!

Comment: This is nothing do with variables or scopes. Your code will run fine in browsers with the same set up that you talked about.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Okay, but normally within my IDE a variable only links to another if the source is somehow connected. So this is really bothering me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When come to js files. IDE's use text search to find references. Which in some cases can lead you to a wrong place.

Comment: Oh... interesting! So it's really a kind of bug... common to several independent IDEs. I will then continue to ignore the "hyper" linking and just continue to believe that the files and variable are NOT related.

Comment: Not always, I would say. IDE's can get confused in different situations. May be the link you are specifying may not be in a place that IDE is aware of. In Intellj idea when you click on a file reference it shows all the files available with that name and have the same directory hierarchy. For and example it show both source file and the file in the build directory as well. Fare enough it doesn't know which one is correct. When come to js functions it is worse. Generic function names are used all over the code base.